Why when I use rb.Translate() it keeps the momentum from the rb.AddForce()?
I am adding game over logic when the player falls out the map. I set the players position to be at the start which in this case is -0.823698401,-12.3304148,-206.559509. I do this to send it back to its position. transform.Translate(-0.823698401f, -12.3304148f, -206.559509f); But for some reason it still has the velocity from  rb.AddForce(Vector3.forward * forwardSpeed * speedMultiplier * Time.deltaTime);. And I don't really know how to cancel it. Here is the whole script if you need it.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 100f;
    public float forwardSpeed = 100f;
    public int speedMultiplier = 5;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public TextCustomizer customizer;

    private bool onGround = true;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && onGround == true)
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * speed);
            customizer.AddScore(20);
        }

        if (transform.position.y < -32) // This block
        {
            customizer.score = 0;
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.zero);
            Debug.Log("Velocity is: " + rb.velocity);
            Debug.Log("Angular velocity is: " + rb.angularVelocity);
            transform.Translate(-0.823698401f, -12.3304148f, -206.559509f);
        }

        rb.AddForce(Vector3.forward * forwardSpeed * speedMultiplier * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground")) 
        {
            onGround = true;
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionExit(Collision other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
        {
            onGround = false;
        }
    }
}


I was trying to make that game over logic again. I put the rb.AddForce(Vector3.zero); to cancel it out but it did not work. I also tried other methods like using the isKinematic and resetting the velocity and angular.

Avoid using Physics functions inside of Update.  The physics system is updated at a fixed step (the physics frame), which happens during FixedUpdate.  Update can run multiple times between physics frames, causes incorrect forces to be applied.  While this may not be a concern right now, at some point later you will find yourself wondering why your calculations arent ending up correct (projectiles, speed/distance calculations, etc..).

To cancel the velocity immediately, set the velocity vector to Vector3.zero.
rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;

Rigidbody.velocity
This should be the same as adding a force of negative velocity, when using ForceMode.VelocityChange.
rb.AddForce(-rb.velocity, ForceMode.VelocityChange);

Another issue is that Transform.Translate does not set the position.

Moves the transform in the direction and distance of translation.

Instead use Rigidbody.position and assign the desired position.

If you change the position of a Rigibody using Rigidbody.position, the transform will be updated after the next physics simulation step


`This should be the same as adding a force of negative velocity.
rb.AddForce(-rb.velocity);I think that depends a bit on what force mode is used .. by default it isForce.. I think your example would requireVelocityChange` in order to actually cancel out to zero regardless of weights etc

@derHugo You are correct, I will update my answer to reflect that.
